# Wordpress site loads in more then one minute and wpadmin panel works fine

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx

I have got an issue where nginx is taking 2 minutes to load php files where admin panel works perfectly. Earlier it was showing 504 but i increase timeout limit so it started to load in 2 min. I tried adding security, removing all plugins and other methods.
My site is added in docker container, there are two containers one for nginx one for php-fpm.
Please help me out i am badly stuck on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: This is almost sure, that the issuse is in your theme. Did you tried to run the page with javascript turned off? And try to measure time of execution https://www.saotn.org/measure-wordpress-loading-time-queries/

Answer (score 0):

First isolate your issue.

Try your setup with a simple php page. In a php page print 'something' and load it in your setup, so you can see if the problem is around your code or on the server side.

If the issue is around Nginx, I would first use a very basic configuration and add features step by step and test all the way.

If you have access to the logs, that would definitely help you pin point where the issue is. You could also use something like https://blackfire.io/docs/introduction blackirefire!

Hope that helps

PS: Perhaps you could provide your docker settings?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i tried putting simple text on php file and load page still it was the same result. This setup works when we launch instance but after a week or few days later suddenly load time is more then a minute.

Comment: Also when i changed the ip of the machinw it worked fine but older ip.it has same issue

Comment: @Chandan I will advise to use a different docker image. I use  https://github.com/Wodby/docker4wordpress and didn't have any issues so far. Give it a try